# How to merge/zip generic lists of differing types (and cast the result to a dictionary)?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, merge

i need to read data from some excel sheets. The data in the excel sheets is already formatted in such a way that i am able to get the desired data by using this method.

This is what i am doing:

```
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(strBld.ToString()))
{
    conn.Open();

    IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> excelDataRaw = 
        conn.Query("select * from [Curves$A:IT]").
        Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>();

    int i = 0;
    string previousKey = null;
    var curve = new List<IEnumerable<object>>();
    var excelData = new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<object, object>>();
    //var excelData = new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, decimal>>();

    foreach (var key in excelDataRaw.Select(dictionary => dictionary.Keys).
        ElementAt(i))
    {
        string key1 = key;
        // gets the data from one column within the excel file
        curve.Add(excelDataRaw.Select(col => col[key1]).
            Where(row => row != null).ToList());

        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            // store the column header
            previousKey = key;
        }

        if (i % 2 == 1)
        {
            // merge the data from the first column (keys)
            // with the data from the second column (values)
            IEnumerable<object> keys = curve[i - 1];
            IEnumerable<object> values = curve[i];
            // cast works but than you can't zip the lists together
            //IEnumerable<string> keys = curve[i - 1].Cast<string>();
            //IEnumerable<decimal> values = curve[i].Cast<decimal>();

            // zip them together on their index
            var dic = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v }).
                ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);

            if (previousKey != null)
            {
                if (!excelData.ContainsKey(previousKey))
                {
                    excelData.Add(previousKey, dic);
                }
            }
        }

        ++i;
    }
}
```

I extract all data from the excel file (excelDataRaw). i then select all data that belongs together into a list (curve) and combine two lists that belong to each other into a dictionary (dic). The final result is a dictionary (excelData) that contains the column head from the excel file as a key (previousKey) and the data relevant to this column head as a dictionary (dic).

I would like to cast the dictionary (excelData) from

```
Dictionary<string, IDictionary<object, object>>
```

into

```
Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, decimal>>
```

but i can't cast object into string or decimal and i can't zip the lists together to get the dictionary (dic) after casting each list to the desired type. Has anyone an idea how to achieve the desired result(type)?

Comment: So, to what data type do you want to cast? In general, it is not possible to have two different types of objects in a single generic collection, unless those two types do have a common ancestor.

Comment: Just edited my question to let the desired type stand out. it is also in the code snippet, the commented excelData line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found a solution, I must have overlooked the obvious yesterday. A good night of sleep helps sometimes :).

```
IEnumerable<object> keys = curve[i - 1];
IEnumerable<object> values =
    curve[i].Where(content => decimal.TryParse(content.ToString(), out num));
    Dictionary<string, decimal> dic =
        keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v }).ToDictionary(
            x => (string)x.k, x => decimal.Parse(x.v.ToString()));
if (previousKey != null)
{
    if (!excelData.ContainsKey(previousKey))
    {
        excelData.Add(previousKey, dic);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExcelDataRaw` is of type `Dictionary<string, IDictionary<object, object>>` so it needs `IDictionary<object, object>` as the value. You can't cast `Dictionary<string,decimal>` into `IDictionary<object,object>` because IDictionary is not a covariant interface - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx.

The solution is either to change the type of `ExcelDataRaw` to `Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, decimal>>` or to keep it as is and when trying to use the values from that dictionary cast those to correct types:

```
foreach(var kv in ExcelDataRaw)
{
   Dictionary<string,decimal> convertedValue=kv.Value.ToDictionary(x=>(string)x.Key,x=>(decimal)x.Value);
   // or convert it even further down the road
   string lookup = "abc";
   decimal v = (decimal)kv.Value[lookup];
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to cast excelDataRaw to Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, decimal>>. the second approach works but i am trying to avoid that